# How do you access application-specific constants in vba from a macro in a different application?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

It's often a requirement to use VBA in one MS Office application to perform actions in another, for example, having an excel macro that performs calculations and then renders a table in powerpoint.

VBA provides useful aliases for constants in VBA, such as `ppBorderRight`= 4.  You can style a table in a powerpoint VBA macro by referring to the constant name instead of needing to keep track of which integer value corresponds to what.

This works fine within a powerpoint macro (pptm file), but fails when called from excel (xlsm file)

How can you refer to these constants from another application?  I have an excel VBA macro that creates a ppt application with `Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")`

I have tried the following approaches within my excel macro:

```
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set activeSlide = pp.ActivePresentation.Slides(pp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
Set myTable = activeSlide.Shapes.AddTable(8, 2, , , 600, 500).Table

myTable.Columns(4).Cells.Borders(ppBorderRight).Weight = 0 'ppBorderRight evaluates to Empty
myTable.Columns(4).Cells.Borders(pp.ppBorderRight).Weight = 0 'Error: Application object has no property 'ppBorderRight'
```

What's the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: By adding the application in References. That adds a type library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mark for the answer.

The answer is to go to Tools -> References in the vba application (`Excel` in my case), and to add a reference to the target application's object library (`Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library` in my case).

[image: vba screenshot]